# Fatal error: Class 'adLDAP' not found

Tags: php, adldap

The file I'm viewing is called examples.php and contains the following code:

```
include (dirname(__FILE__) . "/adLDAP.php");
try {
    $adldap = new adLDAP();
}
```

The error that displays reads:

```
Fatal error: Class 'adLDAP' not found in /var/www/examples.php on line 14
```

Line 14 is:

```
$adldap = new adLDAP();
```

adLDAP.php is in the same folder as examples.php and contains the adLDAP class.

Have I messed up my include statement? I get "no such file or directory" with the other formats I have tried. Feels like I'm missing something obvious.

adLDAP.php instantiates the adLDAP class early on:

```
<?php
namespace adLDAP;

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/collections/adLDAPCollection.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/adLDAPGroups.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/adLDAPUsers.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/adLDAPFolders.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/adLDAPUtils.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/adLDAPContacts.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/adLDAPExchange.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/adLDAPComputers.php');

class adLDAP {
```

etc.

Comment: its namespaced, try `new adLDAP\adLDAP()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`adLDAP` class definition is in `adLDAP` namespace. You need to tell PHP that this class is in this namespace:

```
$adldap = new adLDAP\adLDAP();
```

You can also import this class with `use` keyword:

```
<?php
    include (dirname(__FILE__) . "/adLDAP.php");
    use adLDAP\adLDAP;

    $adldap = new adLDAP;
```

Comment: Yes this was the problem. Thank you for your help.